# Typescript - comparing serialized enum comming from the server

Tags: typescript, enums

I have the following enum:

```
export enum ClearingStatus
{
    APPROVED,
    PENDING
}
```

in this interface:

```
export interface PurchaseResponse
{
    email?: string;
    clearingStatus?: ClearingStatus;
}
```

`PurchaseResponse` is comming from the server as: `{"email":"test@t", "clearingStatus": "APPROVED"}`

I want to compare it with the enum in the clent.

these are not working:

`x.clearingStatus === ClearingStatus.APPROVED`
`x.clearingStatus === ClearingStatus.APPROVED` (compilation error)

this is working,

`x.data.clearingStatus as unknown === ClearingStatus[ClearingStatus.APPROVED]`

this is code smell...

Can you suggest a better and safer approach?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code, `ClearingStatus.APPROVED` is 0 and `ClearingStatus.PENDING` is 1 - those won't compare to your serialized strings.

But you can use a string enum:

```
export enum ClearingStatus
{
    APPROVED = "APPROVED",
    PENDING = "PENDING"
}
```